# Rails 3.1 Active Admin gem: how to manage Admin Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

The question for those, who had worked with Active Admin gem:

I just don't get how should I make a **sign up** and **change password** functions for admin users? Can I do this using Active Admin interface?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the install steps on the active admin github page, one of the steps installs devise for you, creates and admin_user table in your DB and populates it with a default user for you to login as.

See at [GitHub](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin).

Comment: Oh thanx for the link to github, I fogot about it )) there is info in wiki: So when you create a new admin, an email is automatically sent to your new admin. Until the person clicks the link to set his password, it’s impossible to log into the account.

Actually I found the solution (description) of the problem on NetTuts: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/create-beautiful-administration-interfaces-with-active-admin/